# extract specific text from list into column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I am trying to extract certain data from a cell and fill in another cell in the adjacent column. Let me attempt to summarize the problem here:

I have around 5000 row entries.

> A1 ------mixed description 50P 40C 10N mixed description

I would like to have material composition extracted like

> B1-------50% Polyester 40% Cotton 10% Nylon

The 50P 40C 10N part in the A1 description is not standard and can be 50P40C10N, 70P/20W/10N, 40P+60C+10E. Also, say the material combination is from a list of 20 material composition (Acetate, Acrylic, Cotton, Nylon....)

Comment: Please provide some real sample data and a table of material composition and abbreviations (e.g. what is 20W?)

Comment: So, what is the difference between  " 40A 60A " ie 40% Acetate with 60% Acrylic and 40% Acrylic and 60% Acetate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a function.  The below will walk through the source string, keep the numbers, and based on selected characters (P|W|N|C|E) will append the selected literal, i.e. "% Polyester".  To use, select a cell in the column you want the new value and select the cell from the source column.

```
    Public Function ParseMaterials(r As Range) As String
        vOut = ""
        vStr = r.Formula
        For i = 1 To Len(vStr)
            If Mid(vStr, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(vStr, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                vOut = vOut & Mid(vStr, i, 1)
            Else
                If Mid(vStr, i, 1) = "P" Then
                   vOut = vOut & "% Polyester "
                End If
                If Mid(vStr, i, 1) = "C" Then
                   vOut = vOut & "% Cotton "
                End If
                If Mid(vStr, i, 1) = "N" Then
                   vOut = vOut & "% Nylon "
                End If
                If Mid(vStr, i, 1) = "W" Then
                   vOut = vOut & "% Wool "
                End If
                If Mid(vStr, i, 1) = "E" Then
                   vOut = vOut & "% Ermine "
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ParseMaterials = vOut
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it is very brutal...
Take care as the Find() function relies on the capital letters... - avoids the "n" in description...

```
=MID(A1,FIND("P ",A1,1)-2,2)&"% Polyester "&MID(A1,FIND("C ",A1,1)-2,2)&"% Cotton "&MID(A1,FIND("N ",A1,1)-2,2)&"% Nylon"
```

An image showing it working:
[image]